# How to stop the task scheduled in Java

Tags: java

I am using java.util.timer class  and i am writing this code

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
MyTask myTask = new MyTask() //MyTask extends TimerTask
Date alarmDate = new Date();
myTimer.schedule(myTask, alarmDate);
```

and perform multiple task at specific date time by using this method

but i have to stop some of them. How can i do that by method cancel "myTask.cancel(Date date);"?

Comment: do u want to stop a currrently running task ?

Answer (score 1):

`TimerTask.cancel()` takes no arguments. Just call

```
myTask.cancel();
```

Please note the following comment in the API docs for Timer:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the
>   concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which
>   is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or
>   delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the
>   Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads,
>   accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask
>   (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
>   with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

Although it may be slightly more code to implement, it provides better control over the submitted tasks.